# What factors can make a battery appear better or worse than it is?

Tags: electrical, battery

With regards to better, I know surface charge is one so best to leave it for a few hours and check.

Not holding your multimeter properly.

Would the battery being connected to switched off car cables cause a misrepresentation?

Any other factors?

Thanks.

Comment: Not using the multimeter properly.

Comment: Being connected to switched-off car cables could certainly affect the accuracy of the measurement...if there's some load being drawn through those "switched-off" cables.  For a more accurate reading, disconnect at least one pole of the battery from the car's battery cables.